# Play 2.5 and ReactiveMongo 0.11 compilation error: value find is not a member of scala.concurrent.Future

Tags: scala

I have created a simple app with Play!2.5 where data from a form is written to the database for which I use ReactiveMongo 0.11.

Currently I am trying to get the index page to display all the entries in the DB.

My code:

```
    def index = Action.async{

    val cursor: Cursor[User] = collectionF.find(Json.obj()).cursor[User]

    val futureUserList :Future[List[User]] = cursor.collect[List]()

    val futureUserListJsonArray :Future[JsArray] = futureUserList.map{user =>
      Json.arr(user)
    }

    futureUserListJsonArray.map{ user=>
      Ok(user)
    }
  }
```

I receive the following compilation error:

*value find is not a member of scala.concurrent.Future[reactivemongo.play.json.collection.JSONCollection*]

Where the *find* refers to the *collectionF.find()* on the second line.

This is what I have imported with regards to concurrency:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future

import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext
```

Thanks

Comment: As indicated by the compiler the code is calling `find` on a `Future`, which is clearly invalid. I guess what's wanted is to call on a collection ref, there resolved within a `Future`, so you need to use `.map` on `Future`. Nothing specific to ReactiveMongo about that.

Answer (score 0):

As cchantep already pointed out in a comment, you are trying to call `find` on a `Future`, not on ReactiveMongo's `JSONCollection`, and you need a way to access the `JSONCollection` instead.

However, I'm wondering how you ended up using a `Future[JSONCollection]` in the first place. It's not only that I can't imagine a viable reason to do that, it's also cumbersome to use that construct afterwards. Yes, you could use e.g. `map` to get access to the `JSONCollection`, but this means that the returned `Cursor` is also a `Future` (which subsequently forces you to `flatMap` any operation you are doing with the `Cursor`).

```
val cursor: Future[Cursor[User]] = collectionF.map(_.find(...).cursor[User])
val users = cursor.flatMap(...)
```

Have a look at the [documentation](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/documentation/tutorial/play2.html) of ReactiveMongo's play plugin, especially at the examples at the bottom of the page:

```
class Application @Inject() (val reactiveMongoApi: ReactiveMongoApi)
    extends Controller with MongoController with ReactiveMongoComponents {

  // no Future here:
  def collection: JSONCollection = db.collection[JSONCollection]("users")

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried to work around the documentation as Intellij kept giving me error messages, but I got it to work in the end. I'm happier working with this for the time being as I am still quite new to Scala and Play and I am still learning about Futures and asynchronous programming.
I ended up using it as part of a code along tutorial, which (as you can see) can lead to writing code you don't fully understand. So again, thanks for giving me some direction and help me write code I understand completely. It made me improve my project.